# How to use i18next-node-mongodb-backend?

Tags: i18next

Did anyone knows how to store data in mongoDB to be used with https://github.com/gian788/i18next-node-mongodb-backend. Tried couple of things and its not translating keys.

Here is how I am storing my data in mongo

```
{"en" : { "translation" : { "FirstName" : "First Name", "LastName" : "Lastwq Name" } } }
```

While printing it always prints key with error

```
i18next::translator: missingKey en translation FirstName FirstName
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The format is the following :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("581f3645caa6b31c074dd91c"), 
    "language" : "en", 
    "namespace" : "translation", 
    "data" : {
        "FirstName" : "First Name",
        "LastName" : "Lastwq Name"
    }
}
```

Obviously you can change the namespace in the `init` options